# How to make mapping between List<string> and a string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, automapper-2

I have a Model an ViewModel Like this, but AutoMapper doesn't pass the values from MyViewModel to MyModel!

**MyModel:**

```
public List<string> ContentLinks { get; set; }
public string ListOfContentLinks {
    get
    {
        return String.Join(";", ContentLinks);
    }
    set {
        ContentLinks = value.Split(';').ToList();
    } 
}
```

**MyViewModel:**

```
public List<string> ContentLink { get; set; }
```

**Boostrapper:**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyModel>();
```

What do I have to do to make the mapping work correctly?

Comment: Do you get an error from automapper?

Comment: @Mattias Josefsson no error but in data base ListOfContentLinks==null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have properties with same name, then use custom mapping for that member:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyModel>()
      .ForMember(d => d.ContentLinks, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.ContentLink));
```

Answer (score 1):

properties must have the same name for the default mapping. You have `ContentLinks` in one case and `ContentLink` in another